# In a hosted Azure Devops environment is it possible to create notifications for fields not provide out-of-the-box?

Tags: notifications, azure-devops

We are using a hosted AzureDevops (ADO) instance to track requirements, bugs, and manual test runs. I know how to create notifications, and i know how to create new fields in ADO.

My question is: is it possible to create notifications for fields such as "Outcome" which is the result of a manual test case the values of which are `active`, `blocked`, or `failed`.

The goal is to create a notification when: *assignedTo*=@me AND *outcome* CHANGES (although, I'd accept most combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the document [Default and supported notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=azure-devops), We can see it is impossible to create a notification from the test case results on the change of the outcome. For test case results is not a work item, the results changed but the test work item is not changed.

Though it cannot be created in a standard way, you can [create a custom field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops) (named OutCome) by creating an inherited process. And [change your current process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-agile-to-scrum?view=azure-devops#change-the-project-process) to this inherited process

[image]

Then [create a custom notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#add-a-custom-subscription) to send you an email on the change of the field outcome. You have to manually update the outcome field of the test case from **Boards**.

You can also go to [Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to submit **suggest a feature** request. Hopely Microsoft development team will consider this feature and adding the notification for Test case results.

[image]